# Kivy.uix.images is not working returns only blank screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm runing "Kivy" on Windows 10. When I use "Images" in Kivy App... it returns Blank screen..
My code is Following(Code files and Images are in same folder)

```
from kivy.app import App
from  kivy.uix.widget   import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Game(Widget):
   def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.background = Image(source='backGround.jpg')
        self.size = self.background.size
        self.add_widget(self.background)
        self.add_widget(Image(source='bird.jpg'))

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return Game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GameApp().run()
```

Please Someone point out Mistake... I'll be greatful... Regards

Comment: As a first step, try changing the base class of `Game` to some kind of `Layout`. The `Widget` class is not intended as a container for other `Widgets`.

Comment: Thanks bro... I worked out that way....